# How to make RetryWhen retries the stream that throws the exception

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to work a very basic flow using `retryWhen`. 
I'm emitting 3 Flowables and one of them throws an `IOException` which in that case I would trigger the retry up to 2 times.
The problem is that on retry it restarts everything..causing the other flowables to re-emit. 
Here is my code:

```
Flowable.just("AA", "BB", "CC")//
        .flatMap(station -> getStation(station))//
        .retryWhen( RetryWhen
                     .maxRetries(2)
                     .retryWhenInstanceOf(IOException.class)
                     .build())
        .subscribe(//
            station -> System.out.println("Received Availability for station=" + station),
            error -> System.err.println("Failed with error=" + error.getMessage()),
            () -> System.out.println("Completed!")//
        );

private Flowable<String> getStation(String station)
  {
    if (station.equals("CC"))
    {
      System.err.println("Failed staton=" + station + " --> Going to retry");
      return Flowable.error(new IOException("Server for station=" + station + " is down!"));
    }

    System.out.println("Querying for Station=" + station);

    return Flowable.just(station);
  }
```

How to tweak it to make only the one that throws exception retry??

**EDIT**:
According to feedback, I have changed the code to retry on each `Flowable` instance:

```
 Flowable<String> flw1 = getStationAvailability("AA");
        Flowable<String> flw2 = getStationAvailability("BB");
        Flowable<String> flw3 = getStationAvailability("CC");

      Flowable.concat(//
            flw1.retryWhen(RetryWhen.maxRetries(2).retryWhenInstanceOf(IOException.class).build()),
            flw2.retryWhen(RetryWhen.maxRetries(2).retryWhenInstanceOf(IOException.class).build()),
            flw3.retryWhen(RetryWhen.maxRetries(2).retryWhenInstanceOf(IOException.class).build())//
        ).subscribe(//
            station -> System.out.println("Received Availability for station=" + station),
            error -> System.err.println("Failed with error=" + error.getMessage()),// 
            () -> System.out.println("Completed!")//
        );
```

but, what happens is that it doesn't retry at all.
any insights on that?
Thank you!

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't retry? Maybe it fails twice in a quick succession and since you `concat` instead of `merge`, the other flows don't even run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `retryWhen()` operator on the observer chain for the individual observables.

```
Flowable.just("AA", "BB", "CC")//
        .flatMap(station -> getStation(station)
          .retryWhen( retryStrategy ) )//
      .subscribe( ... );
```

That way, the re-subscription occurs on only the one observer chain.

Comment: tried that and it didn't work as expected, please look at my "EDIT".

Comment: I re-wrote my answer to mirror your original code. Sorry for my error.